# Error while running randomForest in R: "Error in y - ymean : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, binary-operators

```
birth <- import("smoker_data1.xlsx")


## Splitting the dataset in test and train datasets

mysplit <- sample.split(birth, SplitRatio = 0.65)
train <- subset(birth, mysplit == T)
test <- subset(birth, mysplit == F)

## Build Random Forest model on the test set

mod1 <- randomForest(smoke~., train)
```

Error message: Error: Error in y - ymean : non-numeric argument to binary operator**

Comment: now the mod1 <-randomForest(smoke~., train) is not running due to the following error:
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to check the data type for smoke variable first.
If possible try to change the variable using as.factor().

```
library(readxl)
birth <- read_excel("smoker_data1.xlsx")
## Splitting the dataset in test and train datasets
mysplit <- sample.split(birth, SplitRatio = 0.65)
train <- subset(birth, mysplit == T)
test <- subset(birth, mysplit == F)
train$smoke <- as.factor(train$smoke)
## Build Random Forest model on the test set

mod1 <- randomForest(smoke~., train)
```

I already tried with the data you gave, just need to specify the type of data correctly before fitting randomForest function.

```
data1$baby_wt <- as.numeric(data1$baby_wt)
data1$income <- as.factor(data1$income)
data1$mother_a <- as.numeric(data1$mother_a)
data1$smoke <- as.factor(data1$smoke)
data1$gestation <- as.numeric(data1$gestation)
data1$mother_wt <- as.numeric(data1$mother_wt)


library(caret)
library(randomForest)
predictors <- names(data1)[!names(data1) %in% "smoke"]
inTrainingSet <- createDataPartition(data1$smoke, p=0.7, list=F)
train<- data1[inTrainingSet,]
test<- data1[-inTrainingSet,]
library(randomForest)
m.rf = randomForest(smoke~., data=train, mtry=sqrt(ncol(x)), ntree=5000,
                    importance=T, proximity=T, probability=T)
m.rf
#############################################
# Test Performance
#############################################
m.pred = predict(m.rf, test[-4], response="class")
m.table <- table(m.pred, test$smoke)
library(caret)
confusionMatrix(m.table)
```

Comment: I have fitted the data that you gave in R. and Run using randomForest function. is seems ok.. you just need to set the data type correctly.